# Raspberrry Pi 4 doesn't display image

Tags: pi-4, boot, power

I just received my raspberry pi 4 and I've got a basic setup ready to go. However when I turn the Pi on nothing displays on screen. I've got a microSD with Raspberry Pi OS installed already.

Here's some info:

- Green light blinks erratically, with no discernable pattern, occasionally stays on for some time, then eventually turns off
- My portable monitor runs on Mini (not micro) HDMI
- I've reformatted the microSD using a formatting software

I've also made a (rough) diagram of my setup below.
[image: My Setup (not to scale)]

Would like to hear some possible solutions. thank you!

Comment: Have you got a regular screen you can test with? I suspect the OS is not recognising your screen.

Comment: Try turning the Pi on with no sd card, connected to that screen. Should see the diagnostics screen.

Answer (score 0):

Please work through the [boot sticky](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151).

If it still doesn't work explain the varous results you had.